# Changes to RSpec Error checking

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I am trying to follow a tutorial on TDD with RSpec that contains the following line:

```
it 'must have a first_name' do
  p = Person.new
  p.should_not be_valid
  p.errors.on(:first_name).should_not be_nil
end
```

However I receive the following message in my test:

> undefined method `on' for #ActiveModel::Errors:0x007fde0c3eceb0>

What is the correct way to write the code above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct function is `errors_on`. So that line should be

```
p.errors_on(:first_name).should_not be_nil
```